# WidgetKit: IntentHandlers for different Intents

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am attempting to create different handlers for different Intents but the class `IntentHandler` does not show the protocol method `provideObjectOptionsCollection` for the second Intent.

I have two widgets and each with their own Intent. I would like to handle the intent individually with their own logic. I have checked that both Intents are added to the info.plist file of the IntentHandler target.

Pseudo code:

```
struct WidgetOneTimelineProvider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    typealias Intent = WidgetOneIntent
    //... all other widget protocol methods
}

struct WidgetTwoTimelineProvider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    typealias Intent = WidgetTwoIntent
    //... all other widget protocol methods
}

class IntentHandler: INExtension, WidgetOneIntentHandling, WidgetTwoIntentHandling {
  
    func provideOptionsCollection(for intent: WidgetOneIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Object>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        //My method handling...
    }

    //Unable to find similar protocol methods for WidgetTwoIntentHandling
        
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
        // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
        return self
    }
}
```

How do I provide methods to handle the different intents?

Comment: What do your intent definitions look like? Do both of your intents have a dynamically-provided parameter? If you open the righthand sidebar and select the Identity Inspector, do both intents have custom classes? You should also be able to click the little arrow to view the generated classes, which is where the intent handling protocols are defined.